# How to integrate the cucumber in testNG?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng

I have a framework which is used to created by core JAVA+TestNG. And the framework is followed by TDD model, and POM is our build management tool. Can somebody tell me is there any possible to update the framework from TDD to BDD using cucumber. But still I would like to do minimum changes for this requirement, like not changing any existing technologies(Core language,TestNG, Maven sys.,). My objective is how to run the cucumber TC's using testNG.xml/TestNG plugins in eclipse. Is it possible to implement the code in Jenkin CI server with minimum changes?

Can somebody share me the basic example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can have CucumberJVM integrated with TestNG, Selenium and Maven.

You can run the tests from Jenkins with `mvn test`.

Here you have a basic example:

http://automatictester.co.uk/2015/06/11/basic-cucumberjvm-selenium-webdriver-test-automation-framework/

Comment: Many thanks for your input. It's really help me to achieve my task.

Comment: link is broken @automatictester can please fix