# Can't run testng.xml in Cucumber-Maven(TestNG)

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng

In eclipse IDE, I have created a basic cucumber framework by using Maven project.

I have added all the dependencies required in pom.xml.For TestNG plugin added below dependencies.

```
 <dependency>       
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>              
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>         
</dependency> 
<dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>   
 </dependency>
```

But 'TestNG Suite' option was not coming in preferences,so installed TestNG through Help->Install New Software.

Framework is having feature file(scenario is described),stepdefinitions(code/logic given) and runner class(To map feature with stepdefinitions file and run it).

**Runner class :**

```
package tests.report.runners;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;


@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features",glue= {"tests"},tags= {"@Report"})
public class ReportRunner  {
    }
```

Like this I have one runner class for each module(End to End scenario)

**Ex :**

- Login, go to product page and logout
- Login,generate report and logout

I am trying to run these runner class by testng.xml file

**testng.xml file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
   <suite name="First Suite" parallel="classes"> 
    <test name="Chrome Test" parallel="classes">
       <classes> 
           <class name ="tests.report.runners.ReportRunner"></class>
       </classes> 
   </test> 
</suite>
```

**But its throwing below error**

[image: Output screen shot]

Comment: update you project. right click on project->maven->update. try then

Comment: I tried  both 'update project' and 'refresh' but it couldn't work.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701094/how-to-implement-and-run-cucumber-test-files-using-testng

Comment: it didn't help.Thanks!

Comment: Follow this link to run cucumber with testng - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/testng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was because of incompatible junk jars stored in maven repositeries.

Please follow below steps

1. Clean old properties/maven dependencies(Open command prompt from yours project directory 
   and run below commands)

   - mvn eclipse:clean
   - mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
2. Download below cucumber jar files and add in your project(don't add it in pom 
   directly)

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
       <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
       <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.5</version>
   </dependency
   <dependency>
       <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
       <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.5</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
       <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
       <version>2.12.2</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Make sure that You have already TestNG library into project
4. Add below cucumber-testng dependencies in pom.xml file

   ```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
5. Extend runner class with AbstractTestNGCucumberTests

> ```
>   package tests.report.runners;
>   import org.testng.annotations.Test;
>   import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
>   import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
>   @Test
>   @CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features",glue= {"tests"},tags= 
>   {"@Report"})
>   public class ReportRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
>   }
> ```

6. Execute with below testng.xml file

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
> <suite name="First Suite" >
> <test name="Chrome Test" >
> <classes>
> <class name ="tests.report.runners.ReportRunner"></class>
> </classes> 
> </test>
> </suite>
> ```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

On the intellij Right pane - click Maven - Reload all maven projects.
Invalidate caches and restart from files.
It will work